# How to hide the keyboard, and add text to EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button

I have a `EditText` and a `Button` .
When you press `EditText`  , I want to not show the `keyboard`  , And when you press the `Button`, I want to type a number 1 on the `EditText`  .

observation 
I want to `cursor` does not disappear .

[![
When you press the 1 1 writes
When you press the Del licked
Can be controlled in the text
Without the appearance of the keyboard ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVqjL.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVqjL.png)

Comment: force to hide the keyboard, add a onclicklistener and do myTextView.setText("1");

Comment: Or you can set the EditText property editable as false, that way it will prevent it from any user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in your EditText xml to disable the keyboard

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Set a "1" on your edit text.

```
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mYourEditText.setText("1");
        }
    });
```

Comment: observation I want to cursor does not disappear .

Comment: then why not use a textview for that? the point of an edit text is that it can take user input, hence the cursor.  now if you really want the styling of an edittext for your textview, that can be easily achieved.

Comment: I want industry calculator
I want to develop, to move my cursor

Comment: Looking for: Move the cursor and turn off the keyboard

Comment: what does it mean by move the cursor?

Comment: I want to become like a button Keyboards

Comment: I mean, I want to put a lot of buttons
Such as the keyboard. When I move my cursor moves. At the press of a button is added No.

Answer (score 0):

Next configuration to your `EditText`:

```
android:longClickable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Add a `onClickListener` to your button:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnCLickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myEditText.setText( myEditText.getText().toString() + "1");
    }
});
```

Comment: observation I want to cursor does not disappear .

Comment: Looking for: Move the cursor and turn off the keyboard